# How export LaTeX to OpenDocument format with Biblatex references

Tags: biblatex, biber, tex4ht

I am trying to export a LaTeX document to OpenDocument (.odt) format. This operation is requested by some publishers which do not know how to handle LaTeX files.

I can't find a way of exporting LaTeX documents **with Biblatex references** in a proper way.

Here is a example. I use [TeX4ht](https://www.tug.org/tex4ht/) to convert .tex files to .odt

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
 author =    {Author},
 title =     {Title},
 publisher =     {Publisher},
 year =      2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{biblio}
\title{Test}
\author{Title}
\begin{document}

Test\cite{author00:_title}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

TeX4ht command lign to export to .odt is :

```
mk4ht oolatex test.tex
```

This command works but create a OpenDocument file without references. References are replaced by their keys (in our example : author00:_title).

The output of `mk4ht oolatex` says about biblatex :

```
No file test.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'author00:_title' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 13.

[1] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
```

So I re-run Biber which found the reference :

```
biber test
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/share/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Config.pm line 864.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblio.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'biblio.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'fr_FR.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nyt' keys
INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to test.bbl
```

And I re-run TeX4ht (`mk4ht oolatex test.tex`) which ends unexpectedly :

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht)) (./test.aux) (./test.bbl
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@begunit ...penalty \@M \hskip -\blx@unitmark 
                                                  \relax \hskip \blx@unitmar...
l.11 Test\cite{author00:_title}

?
```

How can I fix this error and export my biblatex references into odt format?

Comment: with texlive 2013, your sample compiles correctly for me. with sequence latex test; biber test; mk4ht oolatex test

Comment: it could be that the biber backend option was not specified?

Comment: It often depends on the versions of tex4ht and biblatex etc. It often has to be updated to work with specific versions I believe.

Comment: I specified explicitly the biber backend option (with `\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}` lign). No change

Comment: About versions : I'm running Biber 1.7 and mk4ht (2008-06-28-19:09) and tex4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:33 kpathsea). There are unstable debian versions. So it is difficult for me to upgrade... If it is the only solution, please tell me which software I need to upgrade. For example, which versions on what system do you use michal.h21 ?

Comment: sometimes it's just better to `htlatex` (or `mk4ht htlatex`) the source and then open the html file in libreoffice and save it as odt (what can be done in command line, via `libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem (which was export to odt with biblatex references) with pandoc :

```
pandoc test.tex -o output.odt --bibliography /my/bibliography.bib -s
```

Hope It could help another one.

P-S : Tex4ht was definitively not rendering biblatex for me even after upgrade.

Comment: Did you try rendering into PDF and opening PDF in Open Office?

Comment: @ajeh no, sorry!

Comment: But aren't `pandoc` lose things like page breaks?